# SQL Group By expression to return same number of rows

Tags: sql

I am having trouble with returning the same rows in group by expressions in a union query.  The SQL I currently have returns the following result
[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NeJ4.png)
I would like to show equal number of rows in the 2 tables so I need to return a row even if the amount is zero.
[Proposed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8mxk.png).

My SQL currently looks like this

```
    SELECT
    'A' AS Code,
    'Internal Equipment' AS Description,
    'Project A' AS Project,
    Revision,
    'ME' AS Customer,
    Discipline,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM
    Table B
WHERE
    (
        Project = @Project
    )
AND (
        Revision = @Revision
    )
AND Amount > 0
AND RoleCode NOT LIKE 'AAA%'
GROUP BY
    Project,
    Revision,
    Customer,
    Discipline
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'B' AS Code,
    'External Equipment' AS Description,
    'Project A' AS Project,
    Revision,
    'ME' AS Customer,
    Discipline,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM
    Table B
WHERE
    (
        Project = @Project
    )
AND (
        Revision = @Revision
    )
AND Amount > 0
AND RoleCode LIKE 'AAA%'
GROUP BY
    Project,
    Revision,
    Customer,
    Discipline
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'C' AS Code,
    'Labour' AS Description,
    'Project A' AS Project,
    Revision,
    'ME' AS Customer,
    Discipline,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM
    Table A
WHERE
    (
        Project = @Project
    )
AND (
        Revision = @Revision
    )
GROUP BY
    Project,
    Revision,
    Customer,
    Discipline
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'D' AS Code,
    'Travel & Accomodation' AS Description,
    'Project A' AS Project,
    Revision,
    'ME' AS Customer,
    Discipline,
    SUM(Amount).
FROM
    Table B
WHERE
    (
        Project = @Project
    )
AND (
        Revision = @Revision
    )
AND Amount > 0
AND RoleCode IN('BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD')
GROUP BY
    Project,
    Revision,
    Customer,
    Discipline
```

Can someone please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you LoztInSpace, this has solved the problem.  This is a SQL Server database by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways depending on what DB you are using.  I'd probably approach it as follows.

```
with CODES AS
(
SELECT
'A' AS Code, 'Internal Equipment' AS Description
UNION ALL
'B' AS Code, 'External Equipment' AS Description
),
DATA AS
(
...Your SQL HERE (without description)
)
SELECT * from Codes left outer join DATA on (Codes.Code=Data.Code)
ORDER BY CODES.Code
```

You have to decide what to do with the missing values which will be `NULL`.  `COALESCE` is probably the function to use here.

Also, your problem is SELECT/UNION not GROUP BY!